# Simplifying $\sum_{k=0}^{59}{100 \choose k}$

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to solve an equation and I go the following statement:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{59}{100 \choose k}
$$
How can I simplify it? I though to use the Binomial equation but it does not help.

**Edit:** I understand that there it no "pretty" equation. How can I calculate approximility (with 5 digits after the dot)?

Comment: If you sum up to $100$ the sum is $(1+1)^{100}$. Use the symmetry $\binom{100}{k}=\binom{100}{100-k}$.

Comment: I don't know how much you expect to simplify this, but in general there is not a particularly nice closed form simplification for $\sum\limits_{k=a}^b\binom{n}{k}$.  There are special cases, of course, such as when $a=0,b=n$ you get the binomial theorem or if $a=0,b=\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ you effectively get "half" (*or near half*) of the sum you would have expected from binomial theorem.  It looks like about the best you can do easily would be $2^{99}+\frac{1}{2}\binom{100}{50}+\sum\limits_{k=51}^{59}\binom{100}{k}$, which still leaves quite a bit to be desired

Comment: Are you trying to get the exact decimal number, or just an approximation?

Comment: @BarryCipra approximation

Comment: @vesii, in that case it will help to edit the question to say so explicitly, along with an indication of how accurate the approximation needs to be.

Comment: @BarryCipra Thanks, done :)

Comment: The answer is an integer with about $33$ digits. $5$ numbers after the decimal point doesn't make much sense. Perhaps you mean $5$  digits after the decimal point for the coefficient of the power of $10$ when written in scientific notation. Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: @EthanBolker Ah sorry for my English, but what is the difference between a digit and a number when speaking about entities after the decimal point?

Comment: digits and numbers after the decimal point are the same. The answer is an integer, so there are only $0$s after the decimal point. See my answer for the exact value.

Comment: @EthanBolker, the OP may be thinking in terms of an approximation in scientific notation, $a\times10^n$, with $1\le a\lt10$.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a general formula for a truncated binomial sum so the best (I guess) you can do is the binomial theorem to sum the values up to $50$ and then add the last $9$ terms.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{100} \binom{100}{k} =2^{100} \\
\frac{1}{2} \binom{100}{50} +  \sum_{k=0}^{49} \binom{100}{k}  =2^{99} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
and now add the last few terms
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{2} \binom{100}{50} +   \binom{100}{51} +   \binom{100}{52} +   \cdots +   \binom{100}{59}.   \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

The binomial distribution of order $n$ is close to a normal distribution with mean $\frac{n}2$ and variance $\frac{n}4$. In this case, we include up to the interval $(58.5,59.5)$ in a normal distribution with mean $50$ and standard deviation $5$; that is, the probability of a normal variable  being less than $1.9=\frac{59.5-50}{5}$ standard deviations above the mean:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{2^{100}}\sum_{k=0}^{59}\binom{100}{k}
&\approx\mathcal{N}_{0,1}(1.9)\\
&=0.97128344
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{59}\binom{100}{k}
&\approx2^{100}\cdot0.97128344\\
&=1.231248\times10^{30}
\end{align}
$$
As computed in a previous answer:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{59}\binom{100}{k}=1231593588615362909398364442776
$$
so we were only $0.02\%$ off.

Answer (score 0):

[Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28100%20choose%20k%29%20%20k-0%20to%2059) says

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{59} \binom{100}{k} = 1231593588615362909398364442776   
$$